# How to migrate from Nagios + Cacti to Icinga?

Tags: monitoring, nagios, cacti, icinga

I would like to migrate from Nagios + Cacti to Icinga. Because I would like one interface for active and trends monitoring. What could be problems and how to solve them?

Answer (score 2):

The migration from nagios to icinga is very easy. You just need to change 2 options in icinga.conf and restart with your nagios config files and everything is fine.
Migrating cacti is also easy, but its not so easy to integrate it nicely into the webgui, pnp4nagios is the preferred solution of the icinga team and that is integrated into the webgui.